# Не работает слайдер

Tags: jquery, slider

К слайдеру шли эти скрипты:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.5.3/jquery-ui.min.js" ></script>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#featured > ul").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 5000, true);
        });
</script>
```

Но когда подключаю другой плагин:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tourvisor.ru/module/init.js"></script>
```

слайдер перестает работать (не перелистывает картинки).

Опера выдает вот это:

```
jquery-ui.min.js:471 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

В чем дело? Как избавиться от конфликта? Помогите, пожалуйста, уже всё перепробовал, что знал. :(

Comment: @ross, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: похоже на конфликт

Answer (score 1):

У вас, похоже, конфликт двух библиотек, jquery и core.js, попробуйте написать вот так:

```
<script>
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery("#featured > ul").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 5000, true);
   });
</script>
```